# Вызов экземпляра класса в методе другого класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Есть следующий фрагмент кода:

```
import numpy as np

class Points():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def distance(point_2, point_1):
        return np.sqrt((point_2.x-point_1.x)**2+(point_2.y-point_1.y)**2)


class Calculator():
    def distance(point_1, point_2):
        return np.sqrt((point_2.x-point_1.x)**2+(point_2.y-point_1.y)**2)

pt2, pt1 = Points(10, 3), Points(0, 0)
x_1 = Points.distance(pt2, pt1)
x_2 = pt2.distance(pt1)
x_3 = Calculator.distance(pt2, pt1)
```

1) Можно ли так вызывать экземпляры класса `Points`: `pt2` и `pt1` внутри метода  класса`Calcuclator` или нужен какой-то конструктор для `Calcuclator`?

2) Как правильнее организовать классы, то есть для личного восприятия удобнее создание дополнительного класса `Calculator`, оперирующего экземплярами класса `Points` как типом данных или нужно следовать некому принципу концентрации и создавать методы для `Points` внутри `Points`?

P.S. Смущает даже пример получения `x_2`, не симпатично выглядит как-то либо в принципе неправильно организован метод `Points.distance()`. Понятно, что например при организации графа как класса метод `get_nodes` удобно объявить внутри класса, но как поступать в таких ситуациях? А может вообще не нужно писать *over engineered garbage code* и только лишь объявить несколько функций?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Класс не должен знать о каких-то глобальных переменных снаружи себя (тех же `pt1`, `pt2`) - если это не какие-то общие параметры ("константы"). Как сейчас реализовано - такой вариант вполне нормальный, только лучше сделать метод статическим - добавить декоратор `@staticmethod` выше `def distance(point_1, point_2):`
2. В Python в отличие от Java, например, не обязательно все складывать в классы. `Point` можно оставить дата-классом (т.е. использовать только для хранения данных, как структуру в классическом Си), а все функции, работающие с этим классом, хранить в этом же модуле. Вообще лучше не создавать классы общего назначения "на всякий случай" - это прямой путь к антипаттерну [God object](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82). Хотя и модуль, где хранится все подряд, тоже не сильно отличается от такого "божественного" класса.
3. Все три варианта (`x_1`, `x_2`, `x_3`) вполне допустимы, не знаю что вас смущает во втором варианте.
   Если будет работа с графами, то естественно такие функции не стоит добавлять в класс `Point`, а лучше будет создать отдельный класс для графа, а в нем уже определять функции для работы с графами. Тем более, что граф может быть внутри представлен разными способами, и та же функция получения вершин может работать совсем по-разному.

Comment: То есть лучше иметь модуль ```PTS.py``` c классом ```Points```, и объявить не ```Calculator.distance```, а обычную функцию ```distance``` и вызывать в ```main.py``` ```PTS.distance(pt1, pt2)```?

Comment: Лучше `points.py` ([pep8, package and module names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names)), остальное зависит от ситуации. Я бы все-таки использовал вариант `pt1.distance(pt2)` (в случае чего IDE мне подскажет, какие методы есть у класса `Point`, а так еще нужно догадаться, что все методы лежат прямо в модуле).

Comment: Вариант ```pt1.distance(pt2)``` мне просто *кажется* не интуитивным, при обработке экземпляров класса в мозгу пока как-то легче укладывается вариант вызова ```x_1```. Но отныне буду создавать ```distance``` внутри класса, который в отдельном модуле и вызывать.